# How can I save prestashop invoices automatically and manually?

Tags: python, pdf-generation, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, invoice

**I want to print out an invoice(pdf) automatically, what's recently saved on the server. And also making manual saving possible**

I'm using prestashop 1.6.1 and the invoices are mostly downloaded from the prestashop admin page, but I needed more easier way to print out these invoices, so I made an adminpage for myself it looks like this:
[image]

The printer button has a href of the invoice generated address
like:"*http://www.example.com/admin/index.php?controller=AdminPdf&submitAction=generateInvoicePDF&id_order=3230"*

From the link I can download it and then print it when it's opened in pdf reader, but I want to do this in one click.

Soo... I made an script for automatically printing the pdf when its saved on some specific location

```
    #! /usr/bin/python import os
import os
import time
import os.path
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler



class ExampleHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event): 
    output=str(event.src_path.replace("./",""))
    print(output)
        #print event.src_path.replace("./","")
        print "Got event for file %s" % event.src_path
    os.system("lp -d HL2250DN %s" % output)

observer = Observer()
event_handler = ExampleHandler() 
observer.schedule(event_handler, path='.',recursive=False)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

### There is two options to download it automatically to the server

**1. Override PDF.php and PDFGenerator.php files like this:**

**PDF.php**

```
class PDF extends PDFCore
{
    public function render($display = true)
    {
        if($this->template == PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE)
            parent::render('F', true);

        return parent::render($display);
    }
}

?>
```

**PDFGenerator.php**

```
    <?php

 class PDFGenerator extends PDFGeneratorCore
{
    public function render($filename, $display = true)
    {
        if (empty($filename)) {
            throw new PrestaShopException('Missing filename.');
        }

        $this->lastPage();

        if ($display === true) {
            $output = 'D';
        } elseif ($display === false) {
            $output = 'S';
        } elseif ($display == 'D') {
            $output = 'D';
        } elseif ($display == 'S') {
            $output = 'S';
        } elseif ($display == 'F') {
            $output = 'F';
            $filename = '/folder/for/print_it/'.str_replace("#", "", $filename);
        } else {
            $output = 'I';
        }

        return $this->output($filename, $output);
    }
}

?>
```

**2. Use script to download**

### First attempt

The first option worked for automatic saving, but when I tried to save invoices manually I got an blank or broken pdf file. I also tried to change the pdf.php, but it dident work out for me. Also made an post about this: [Prestashop saving invoices manually and automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544165/prestashop-saving-invoices-mannualy-and-automatically). No answers were given and I moved on second option.

### Second attempt

I tried to download invoices with python script and it worked, but how can I know which one to download?

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import webbrowser

url = "http://www.example.com/admin/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=5a01dc4e606bca6c26e95ddea92d3d15"
url2 = "http://www.example.com/admin/index.php?controller=AdminPdf&token=35b276c05aa6f5eb516737a8d534eb66&submitAction=generateInvoicePDF&id_order=3221"
payload = {'example': 'example',
    'example': 'example',
    'stay_logged_in':'2',
    'submitLogin':'1',}

with requests.session() as s:
    # fetch the login page
    s.get(url)

    # post to the login form
    r = s.post(url, data=payload)
    print(r.text)

    response = s.get(url2)

    with open('/tmp/metadataa.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Soo the problem with this option is that.. How can I pass the href(what was clicked from the printer button) to url?

Solving this has been really frustrating and I know there is an simple and easy option for this, but I'm still looking for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you generate invoice PDF you are forcing it to be saved as local file.

What you want to do is add an extra GET parameter to the print button and check for its presence in the overriden class so that the PDF only gets stored as local file when you want to print directly.

So first add a GET parameter to print buttons eg. `&print=1`. Either in your template or wherever you are generating these buttons so that the button's href looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/admin/index.php?controller=AdminPdf&submitAction=generateInvoicePDF&id_order=3230&print=1
```

Now you can check if parameter exists in `PDF` class and only then force the PDF to be outputted to local file.

```php
class PDF extends PDFCore
{
    public function render($display = true)
    {
        if($this->template == PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE && Tools::getValue('print') == 1) {
            // Output PDF to local file
            parent::render('F');
            // Redirect back to the same page so you don't get blank page 
            Tools::redirectAdmin(Context::getContext()->link->getAdminLink('AdminMyController'));
        }
        else {
            return parent::render($display);
        }
    }
}
```

You can keep the overriden `PDFGenerator` class as is.